# How to restrict UIScrollViewDelegate apply to only one view in UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I am working on an iOS app in Swift. In the app, I have a HomeViewController which has two views - a UICollectionView and UITableView.

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,
      UITableViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

     @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
     @IBOutlet weak var carouselCollectionView: UICollectionView!
}

extension HomeViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
     func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint,
     targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

        let layout = self.carouselCollectionView?.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        let cellWidthIncludingSpacing = layout.itemSize.width + layout.minimumLineSpacing
        var offset = targetContentOffset.pointee
        let index = (offset.x + scrollView.contentInset.left) / cellWidthIncludingSpacing
        let roundedIndex = round(index)
        offset = CGPoint(x: roundedIndex * cellWidthIncludingSpacing - scrollView.contentInset.left, y: -scrollView.contentInset.top)
        targetContentOffset.pointee = offset
     }
}
```

HomeViewController confirms to the UIScrollViewDelegate - scrollViewWillEndDragging as I wanted the collectionView to scroll with some specific behavior. 
Problem is when I am scrolling the tableView it snaps back to the top.

I want the default scrolling behavior for the tableView.
How can I force only the collectionView to use the UIScrollViewDelegate?

Comment: can't you directly compare scrollView == self.carouselCollectionView?

Answer (score 0):

Create additional manager classes for the tableview and collectionview. That way you can set the delegate for each to their own manager class. It’ll help keep the code cleaner and clearer as to what is controlling what and will allow you to put the scrollview logic into one of the managers rather than bloating your view controller with all of the delegate methods for everything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am fairly new to Swift and learning how to improve/have clean code. Is this the approach you are talking about - Create two container views (one for each view)  on the HomeViewController and manage then individually in their respective view controllers?

Comment: There’s a number of different patterns to learn about. I’d suggest reading a bit about MVC and MVVM. But in genera for something like this having separate classes that conform to the collectionviewdelegate and making an instance of that class the delegate for the table view and a different class the delegate for the other will allow you to clearly know what code runs for what object.

Comment: I created a custom delegate class for collectionview delegate which also conforms to UIScrollViewDelegate - `class CustomCollectionViewDelegate: NSObject, UICollectionViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate { }` and assigned the instance of the class to the Collection View in the controller `var customDelegate = CustomCollectionViewDelegate()    carouselCollectionView.delegate = customDelegate`. Now that my outlet variable is in HomeViewController, how do I access the outlet in the delegate method? I need that for fetching the layout for the collectionview to know the exact scroll offset.